# Stuck at loading FB Android Sdk

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I have followed facebooks tutorial and setup the sso key and have integrated the sdk into my code. After logging into facebook via the facebook.authorize it brings me to a new screen which just says "loading" and sits there.

There are no errors in logcat / console and if I press the back button it just says I cancelled the login process.

I am testing on a device. 
All the required permissions are there (internet) 
I've also tested on the emulator and it sits at the same point. 
I've also tried disabling the SSO via Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH and after logging in I get a blank screen as well.

Thanks

Comment: which device u testing on? version?

Comment: i had similar issue, it was due to ssl exception (not trusted server certificate) while getting the access token - on some android devices...does it run on the emulator?

Comment: Nope on the emulator I get the same thing

Comment: im having the same problem and cant find the solution, did you find what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well, I know this is a very old question but I just happened to stumble upon this problem last night. I solved by:

1. Updating my FB client in my phone
2. Making sure the date/time were correct on the device.

Answer (score -1):

Try and disable any adblock such as adfree or adaway if present. It caused me similar issue when trying with Parse.